# How to write Tag Wikis

Tags: discussion, tags

I find many of our tag wikis to be recursive, to say the least, especially for the more difficult ones. What should a tag wiki include to be as useful as possible?

Comment: Can you link some examples for discussion?

Comment: Related question on MSO: [Tag Wiki Best Practices?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69584)

Comment: The following tags seem relevant: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/dnd4.0/info http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/social/info

Comment: I think what's being sought here are examples of good tag wikis to use as examples, as those of us new to SO are looking for a good place to stand.